# A proposition about the discrete topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space.If $T$ contains all the infinite subsets of $X$ , prove that $(X,T)$ is the discrete topological space.

Here it is what i did:

Let $x$$\in$ $X$.
Then $X$ \ $\{x\}$ is infinite.So $X$ \ {$x$,$y_1$,,,,$y_n$,,,,,} is an infinite subset of $X$ that contains $x$ (I constracted this set the {$x$,$y_1$,,,,,,} with induction and this set has all its points distinct and is infinite so it belongs to $T$.
If we take $A$=$X$\ {$y_1$,$y_2$,,,,,} then A$\in$$T$.
So $A$ $\cap${$x$,$y_1$,$y_2$,,,,,}={$x$} $\in$ $T$ from the axioms of the definition of topology sto the singletons are open thus the space ($X$,$T$) is the discrete topological space.
By set theory every infinite set has an infinite subset but my problem is that is $X$ \  {$y_1$,,,,} an infinite subest of  $X$?
In general is my attempt to proves this wright or am i mising something here?
Iwould like some help.Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to assume that $X$ is infinite for this to be true.

Comment: Right idea but seems too complicated. For any $x$ simply partition $X - \{x\}$ into two disjoint infinite sets $A$ and $B$ then use $A \cup \{x\}$ and $B \cup \{x\}$.

Comment: it is by the  statement i forgot to mention it and by the axioms of topology X belongs to T